# Run Ubuntu in "test mode"

Tags: command-line, virtualization, container

Since Linux distributions are extremely powerful, it can also allow the user to type a terminal command that breaks / uninstalls some important part of the OS. Is it possible to run the system in some "temporary mode", test a terminal command or anything else, and if something breaks, one can just exit this mode and return to the "real" OS?

I know I could do one of the following:

- Install a second Ubuntu for testing on the disk (imo this is too much space considering I only need to try some terminal commands).
- Install Ubuntu in a VM (a VM is too limited and has the same problem as the first point)
- Some type of container?

Any other options? I am just curious since I have reinstalled the system so many times now because of something breaking.

Comment: Did you mean "Try Ubuntu without installing"? The option is available as soon as you boot LiveUSB. I generally do experiments which can break the system in a virtual machine.

Comment: The live USB does not allow me to install anything or modify it in any way.

Comment: Sounds weird since I can install any piece of software less than some GBs. But everything vanishes after reboot. You can try making a persistent USB. But in my opinion virtual machine is a better option

Comment: The guest account ?

Comment: I never though about the guest account, that sounds exactly as what i need, no installs and does not break my own account. Can you set it as an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: FWIW, I use a virtual machine for the same purpose.

Comment: @mth1417un Unfortunately guest accounts are not fully contained, so you might want to avoid them. See https://askubuntu.com/q/926081/301745

Comment: What about a standard user then? Just not my own user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can at least use containers and KVM to achieve that by using snapshots.

For LXD this might be as easy as:

```
lxc launch ubuntu-daily:b b
lxc exec b bash
# do some work
lxc snapshot b b-state-1
# do some other work, but revert later
lxc revert b b-state-1
```

If you realize a config is nice you can even clone keep this container but clone the old snapshot to a new name to continue with other experiments. The options are nearly limitless. See sections "Snapshot management" and "Cloning and renaming" in this [blog](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2016/03/22/lxd-2-0-your-first-lxd-container). From there you can go as needed.

And if even with all the nice features system containers have these days that isn't enough you can achieve the same with [libvirt and snapshots](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/virsh.1.html#snapshot%20commands) for VM Guests with Disks or even live snapshots depending on your needs.